# Using of variable in the loop for R

Tags: r, variables, loops

I have data that have column names that are LABELXYZ123_river,  LABELXYZ123_lake,  LABELXYZ345_river, LABELXYZ345_lake,etc....I have a list of the the actual variables 
LABELXYZ123, LABELXYZ345, etc... I want to plot river and lake data for each label on seprate figure. I came with that code, that doesn't work. I think the problem with variable and it's name. Could you please suggest me the solution? Thank you...

```
data <- read.table("data.txt",header=T,row.names=1)
lst  <- c("LABELXYZ123","LABELXYZ345")
for(i in lst) {
lbl_river <- paste("data","$",LABELXYZ123,"_river",sep="")
lbl_lake <- paste("data","$",LABELXYZ123,"_lake",sep="")
allt <- c(lbl_lake,lbl_river)
png(filename=i".png")
plot(paste(lbl_river,xaxt='n',xlab="",ylab="i",type="b",col="darkgreen",lwd=3,ylim=c(min(allt),max(allt)))
lines(paste(lbl_lake,type="b",col="darkred",lwd=3)
dev.off()
}
```

lbl_river it's actually `data$LABELXYZ123_river`

Comment: What are are you trying to plot with the plot function (what is your x axis? what is your y axis?).

Comment: You are making it difficult for your self trying to construct `R` expressions using `paste` (which you would then have to `call` for your code to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying hard to salvage something ....   More to come when the plotting is sorted out

```
data <- read.table("data.txt",header=T,row.names=1)
lst  <- c("LABELXYZ123","LABELXYZ345")
for(label_name in lst) {
  lbl_river <- data[[paste(label_name, "river", sep = "_"]]
  lbl_lake  <- data[[paste(label_name, "lake", sep = "_"]]

}
```

Comment: Your plotting code will not be working, if the code you have in the question is what you are using!

Comment: I rewrote it using the idea of subsetting the data using your quesry - that's work perfectly. Take a look below

Answer (score 0):

Using mnel advice...

```
data <- read.table("data.txt",header=T,row.names=1)
lst  <- c("LABELXYZ123","LABELXZZ123","LABELXYZ345","LABELXYZ567","LABELXYY1234","LABELXXX123")
labs <- row.names(data)
for(i in lst) {
    png(filename=paste(i,".png",sep=""),width = 700, height = 350)
    river  <- data[[paste(i, "_river", sep = "")]]
    lake <- data[[paste(i, "_lake", sep = "")]]
    allt <- c(river,lake)
    plot(river, xaxt='n',xlab="",ylab=i,type="b",col="darkred",lwd=3,ylim=c(min(allt)*1.05,max(allt)*0.95))
    lines(lake,type="b",col="darkgreen",lwd=3)
    axis(1,at=1:16,labels=labs,las=2)
    dev.off()
}
```